# Android seek-bar divide sectors

Tags: android, seekbar

i'm developing an app which display food item prices in android seek-bar..food items has 3 main prices(small, regular and large).
I wanted the seek bar to move only to 0th(small price), 100th(large price) and middle(regular price) positions only, and display the price of regular if seek-bar is in middle position, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is not to use such a large range from 0 to 100.
Use SeekBar.setMax(2) to restrict values to 0, 1, 2.  Then let those values represent your three different sizes.

0 = small, 1 = medium, 2 = large.

This should give you the behavior you are looking for to divide the SeekBar into 3 sectors.